# Match multiline XML with regex and sed or awk

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I know that it is not the best way to match xml with sed or awk and regex, but I have no other choice in the environment I am encountering this problem.

I did not find any answer which solves my problem.

Following XML content:

```
<testTag name="findThisName">
    <content>...</content>
</testTag>
<testTag name="doNOTfindThisName">
   <content>...</content>
</testTag>
```

The regex should match the whole tag with name findThisName including all content. With this regex it works, but only if the content is in one line:

```
<testTag name(?:(?!<\/testTag>).)*findThisName.*?<\/testTag>
```

Anybody has an idea how this can be solved with sed or awk? Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do with the tag once you've found it?

Comment: Just get rid of it, simple delete... ;)

Comment: what environment are you working on so that you don't have access to other tools?

Answer (score 1):

`awk` does not have all of perl's regex features but this might work for you:

```
$ awk '/<testTag[^>]*name="findThisName"/,/<\/testTag>/{next} 1' file
<testTag name="doNOTfindThisName">
   <content>...</content>
</testTag>
```

#### How it works

awk allows us to specify a range of lines in the form `/regex1/,/regex2/` which will match lines starting with `regex1` and ending with the first occurrence of `regex2`.  We use this to skip over the unwanted lines:

- `/<testTag[^>]*name="findThisName"/,/<\/testTag>/{next}`

  For all lines in the range that starts with `<testTag[^>]*name="findThisName"` and ends with `<\/testTag>`, skip to the next line.

  The chosen starting regex, `<testTag[^>]*name="findThisName"`, allows `testTag` to have several attributes.  We do not require that `name="findThisName"` be the first attribute.
- `1`

  For all other lines, tell awk to print them. `1` is awk's cryptic shorthand for print a line.  If you prefer being explicit, replace this with `{print $0}`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this seems to work in awk. Since you mentioned deleting this tag, I'm not printing out those lines.  Note this will fail with nested testTags.

```
awk 'BEGIN {open=0} 
    $0 ~ /<testTag name="findThisName">/ {open=1}
    open==1 && $0 ~ /<\/testTag>/ {open=0; next;}
    open==1 {next;}
    open==0 {print;}'
```

Marks when its found the start tag, then checks if it ends on the same line and removes it if so.  If not, skips lines until its hits the closing tag.  Outside of the desired tag it just prints.

Using this test input:

```
<testTag name="findThisName">
    <content>1<content>
</testTag>
<testTag name="doNOTfindThisName">
   <content>...</content>
</testTag>
<testTag name="findThisName">
    <content>2</content>
</testTag>
<testTag name="doNOTfindThisName">
   <content>...</content>
</testTag>
<testTag name="doNOTfindThisName">
   <content>...</content>
</testTag>
<testTag name="doNOTfindThisName">
   <content>...</content>
</testTag>
<testTag name="findThisName">
    <content>3</content>
</testTag>
<testTag name="doNOTfindThisName">
   <content>...</content>
</testTag>
```

It seems to work as expected:

```
~$ awk 'BEGIN {open=0}
        $0 ~ /<testTag name="findThisName">/ {open=1}
        open==1 && $0 ~ /<\/testTag>/ {open=0; next;}
        open==1 {next;}
        open==0 {print;}' testxml.txt

<testTag name="doNOTfindThisName">
   <content>...</content>
</testTag>
<testTag name="doNOTfindThisName">
   <content>...</content>
</testTag>
<testTag name="doNOTfindThisName">
   <content>...</content>
</testTag>
<testTag name="doNOTfindThisName">
   <content>...</content>
</testTag>
<testTag name="doNOTfindThisName">
   <content>...</content>
</testTag>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '/<testTag name="findThisName"/{f=1} !f; /<\/testTag>/{f=0}' file
<testTag name="doNOTfindThisName">
   <content>...</content>
</testTag>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a full regex match then don't bother with one. Something like the following should work for you.

```
awk '
# Find the start line and set our flag.
/^<testTag name="findThisName">$/ {f=1}

# Print the line if we aren't currently in the flagged tag.
!f {print; next}

# Find the end of the flagged tag and unset our flag.
f && /^<\/testTag>$/ {f=0}
'
```

This won't work for nested `<testTag>` elements though as the first `</testTag>` will trigger the unflagging block.